# Windows 10 store won't connect to the internet

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, windows-store

I have Windows 10, and the store won't connect to the internet. The funny thing is, all my browsers (including Edge) work fine. Not only is the store not working, neither is Cortana, and I can't connect a Microsoft account to the computer. The problem is the same for other accounts.

```
Windows store error code: 0x80072EFD
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCAir.png]

As you can see, Chrome is working perfectly (Firefox is too, but it's just hidden), while the Windows store is having problems with internet.

Comment: Try this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/windows-10-store-server-stumbled-with-error-code/f96d5c80-8cd2-466e-8722-b76cfe274f82

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhw8m4Egf_c

Comment: 0x80072EFD = ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT. Make sure the DNS client service is running

Comment: 5 years later and the problem still exists...

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes using proxy to connect to the internet may cause issues while connecting to the network.
Follow the steps below to disable proxy:

1. Open the New Modern **Settings**
2. Select **Network & Internet**
3. Go to **Proxy**
4. Disable **Use Proxy Server**

Now Open Windows Store it should work if it doesn't try to also Disable **Automatically Detect Settings** & **Use Script Setup**.
Alternately Try Enabling them, & some enable disabled combination with these 3 options.

[image: See Screenshot]

Even after that if it doesn't opens Try the Following:

Navigate to

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache`

and delete all the files and folders. Open the store. Now it should open.

Comment: Deleting `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe` was the only way I could resolve a similar connection error `0x800704cf`.

Comment: Disabled all the 3 options(Automatically detect settings, Use setup script and use a procy server), also delete all files and folders under the specified folder. the ```0x800704cf``` is still here......

Comment: After trying all of these solutions, the trick for me was to disable my ethernet adapter and to use the wifi one

Answer (score 1):

According to [TheWindowsClub.com website article](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/edge-store-apps-not-connecting-internet) and [this question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/microsoft-edge-and-other-microsoft-store-apps/75ac54dd-cd56-41d8-a205-7948e54f39be), if Windows UWP apps (Store, News, Edge, etc) are not able to connect to the internet with **Error 80072EFD**, then you might need to enable IPv6 if it's disabled.              **,         .**.

> To get started, press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `ncpa.cpl`
>   and hit the Enter button. On this page, you can find your currently
>   connected network profile. Right-click on it and select
>   **Properties**.
>
> Make sure you are in the **Networking** tab. Following that, search
>   for **Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)** and select the
>   corresponding checkbox.
>
> [image: Screenshot]

If this doesn't work your problem, please check these articles. They might help you.

- [Windows 10 not connecting to the internet](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-not-connecting-to-the-internet/a6140919-8093-40ad-9603-7754a3bde21e)
- [Microsoft Edge browser is not connecting to the internet Windows 10.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/microsoft-edge-browser-is-not-connecting-to-the/7ac35330-015b-421a-b2ed-3f91862d0941)
- [Fix: Microsoft Edge not working in Windows 10](https://windowsreport.com/microsoft-edge-windows-10-crash/#7)

---

<sup>***References***</sup>

<sup>• [Edge and Store apps not connecting to Internet – Error 80072EFD](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/edge-store-apps-not-connecting-internet)</sup>
<sup>• [Microsoft Edge and other Microsoft Store apps might not connect to the Internet after installing the Windows 10 October 2018 update](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/edge-store-apps-not-connecting-internet)</sup>

Comment: tried this as well, not worked for the ```0x800704cf``` issue.

Answer (score -2):

Experienced the 0x80072efd problem. Has cost me hours if not days to solve. The solution that gave instant resolution is the following command from a admin command prompt:

`netsh winhttp reset proxy`

Answer (score -2):

```
 I gotta solution buddy!! Try this..
 1. Press Win+R keys together to launch RUN dialog box, Type services.msc in the textbox and press Enter to open Services Manager.
 2. Double-click on "Windows Update" in the list.and set its Startup type to Automatic.
 3. Now you're ready to download any app from Windows Store.
```