# Microsoft Store check your connection - error code 0x80072EFD however browsers can connect

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

I have Windows 10.0.017134, build 17134, version 1803.

The Microsoft Store won't connect to the internet; all my browsers connect. I get an error code: 0x80072EFD.

[image: Microsoft Store error code:0x80072EFD]

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 Version 1803?  Edit your question to include this vital information, be sure you provide us which build number you are using, you can use `winver` to provide this information.

Comment: Windows 10.0.017134 build 17134

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 store won't connect to the internet](https://superuser.com/questions/1080919/windows-10-store-wont-connect-to-the-internet)

Comment: I've followed the solutions on the answer and still unable to connect.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy by chance?

Comment: I don't have proxy enabled but the isp service we use might have a proxy.

Comment: Which solutions [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/check-your-connection-error-code-is-0x80072efd) didn't work?  Verify this isn't simply a DNS issue.