# Windows 11 App Store cannot update

Tags: windows, microsoft-store

When I start Windows 11 App Store, it takes a while loading an error message with error code:
0x80072EFD

as follows

[image]

I tried to reset it, and clear its cache as follows:

From Settings -> App & Features

And from the app, I select "Microsoft Store"

And then "Advanced options", and then I choose "Repair" and then "Reset"
Nothing works

Comment: Try ruining (Admi) DISM.exe /online. /cleanup-image. /restorehealth ; restart ; and test

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 store won't connect to the internet](https://superuser.com/questions/1080919/windows-10-store-wont-connect-to-the-internet)

Comment: This error isn’t caused by system corruption so DISM cannot resolve this particular error, it’s cause by the application, being unable to reach the internet. You should make sure you are NOT behind a proxy that has blocked said communication and/or used any application to disable spying on Windows 11.  If you have used such a program then the simplest solution is to reinstall Windows 11 due to changes those tools made to configuration

Answer (score -1):

I made a powershell script that might help. It takes about 30 seconds or more to load all apps. Once loaded you can re-register any app that has this or similar issues. Here's the link [ReRegMSStoreApps](https://github.com/Devenom1/ReRegMSStoreApps)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).